# how to have colors that depends on the value of a column in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I a using plotly ***python*** and I would like to have a graph with colours that depends of the value of my dataframe column.

My code is as follows:

```
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=Rdt_risque['Risque'],
                                y=Rdt_risque['Perf'],
                                mode="markers",
                                marker_color=Rdt_risque['Style'], # I thought that was working but it is not !  
                                marker=dict(size=12),
                                customdata=np.stack((Rdt_risque['Sharpe'],
                                                        Rdt_risque['Nom'], 
                                                        Rdt_risque['Perte Max']),
                                                    axis=-1),
                                hovertemplate='<br>'.join(['<b>%{customdata[1]}</b>',
                                                            'Perf: %{y:,.1f}%',
                                                            'Volat: %{x:,.1f}%',
                                                            'Sharpe: %{customdata[0]:,.2f}',
                                                            'Perte Max: %{customdata[2]:,.1f}%',
                                                            '<extra></extra>'
                                                            ]
                                                            ),
                                showlegend=False
                                )
                )
```

I add that in Rdt_risque['Style'] there are strings.

I can have output I want with this simple instruction but can get the hover template that I want.

```
fig = px.scatter(Rdt_risque, 
                  x='Risque', 
                  y='Perf', 
                  color='Style'
                  )
```

Any help will be helpful

i am trying to have a plotly scatter plot with colors that depend on dataframe columns

Comment: For an example of how to customize the hover template in plotly.express, see this in the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#disabling-or-customizing-hover-of-columns-in-plotly-express).